# Change the color of an Image in Google Sliders

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

I'm trying to change the color to an image in  Google Sliders, but I can't find the function.
The part of the code that I use to find the image I want to modify.

```
var presentation = SlidesApp.openById("ID");
var images =  presentation.getSlides()[0].getImages();
```

[image: An image of the issue]

I leave the  Google Sliders screen from where the change is made

Answer (score 0):

In the current stage, it seems that the Google Slides service (`SlidesApp`) cannot achieve the change of the image color. And also, even when Google Slides API is used, this cannot be achieved. When the official document is seen, the following document can be confirmed. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#Page.ImageProperties)

> recolor: The recolor effect of the image. If not set, the image is not recolored. This property is read-only.

From these situations, I thought that in the current stage, the change of image color on Google Slides cannot be achieved by the Slides service and Slides API. Unfortunately, I think that this is the current answer.

When I checked this at Google issue tracker, I couldn't find it. So how about reporting this as a future request? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

#### References:

- [UpdateImagePropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updateimagepropertiesrequest)
- [ImageProperties](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#imageproperties)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, since somewhere I read it but could not create it that it is not supported

Comment: @Mvillani Thank you for replying. I apologize for this current situation.